# Mypy - Django custom user form gives 'name is not defined'

Tags: python, django, pycharm, mypy

Mypy is not happy with the following custom user form (sub class).

*forms.py*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username',)
```

Mypy throws the following error:

```
Mypy found 1 error:
    Name 'UserCreationForm.Meta' is not defined
```

What can I do to prevent this error? I am new to Mypy and I can't find the solution in the documentation. Thanks in advance for your help!

(PyCharm, Python 3.7, Django 2.2)